# Fraction line with rounded corners

Tags: math-mode, rules, fractions

I want to make the rounded corners of the fraction line. Is it possible ?
[image]

**Update:**

Or you can add rounded corners to all parts of TeX.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz}
%
\newcommand{\thickfrac}[2]{\genfrac{}{}{1.pt}{0}{#1}{#2}}
\newcommand\bigfrac[3][1.0pt]{%
{\thickfrac{\hspace{#1}#2\hspace{#1}}{\hspace{#1}#3\hspace{#1}}}}
\let\oldfrac\frac
\let\frac\bigfrac
%
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\[\frac{a+b+c}{a-b-c}\]
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: not with frac or genfrac you could of course just use tikz and draw it all by hand as you just did for neq in your last question, but you would have to emulate all of tex's normal logic for positioning numerator and denominator

Comment: Do you want to add rounded corners to all parts of TeX?

Comment: @Gaussler Yes i would like

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I think this will be quite difficult

Comment: your choice. It is that, or use the same as all the millions of tex users that have gone before and use a plain rule with straight ends. if you just want simple fractions for a beamer slide you can probably re-use the rounded rules from the `\neq` question for simple cases. For a full publication I would use tex typesetting and a font as designed and remove all the per-character distortions. perhaps if you use luatex you could traverse the node tree generated by tex and replace the rule by a rule with rounded ends, perhaps...

Comment: Thank you for your valuable comment. @DavidCarlisle

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you use LuaTeX, you can do this by customizing the `process_rule` callback. When `\mathrulesmode=1` is set, this affects all rules TeX generates in math modes and "user rules" (a special type of rule which does not occur in normal documents).

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\directlua{
  luatexbase.add_to_callback('process_rule', function(r, h, v)
  print(r, h, h)
    h, v = 100 * h / tex.sp'100bp', 100 * v / tex.sp'100bp'
    print(h, v)
    if h > 8 * v then
      pdf.print('direct', string.format('[] 0 d 1 J \csstring\%.5f w 0 \csstring\%.5f m \csstring\%.5f \csstring\%.5f l S', v, v/2, h, v/2))
    elseif v > 8 * h then
      pdf.print('direct', string.format('[] 0 d 1 J \csstring\%.5f w \csstring\%.5f 0 m \csstring\%.5f \csstring\%.5f l S', h, h/2, h/2, v))
      pdf.print('direct', string.format('[] 0 d 1 J \csstring\%.5f w 0 0 m 0 \csstring\%.5f l S', h, v))
    else
      pdf.print('direct', string.format('1 j \csstring\%.5f w 0 0 \csstring\%.5f \csstring\%.5f re f', math.max(h, v)/8, h, v))
    end
  end, 'rounded_rules')
}
\mathrulesmode=1

\begin{document}
\[\frac{\sqrt{a}+b+c}{a-b-c}\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Great! Is there easy documentation about the callbacks?

Comment: @projetmbc There isn't.

Comment: Where did you find the info for your answer?

Comment: @projetmbc The existance of the `process_rule` callback is documented (in the LuaTeX manual) but only for user rules, the fact that it's also useful for math rules with `\mathrulemode` is directly derived from reading the source code.

Comment: Thanks for this clarification.

Comment: Thank you very much for your support @MarcelKruger